# Is there a way to make this C# comparison code more generic?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I am comparing two objects of the same type and returning the differences into a list of `FieldChange` objects. Right now I am listing out each field comparison like this which seems a bit suboptimal.

Is there a cleaner way of refactoring the code below to avoid the repetition?  There are two sets of code below but in reality I have about 20 comparisons.

```
var changes = new List<FieldChange>();
if (proposedUpdatedProject.StatusId != existingProject.StatusId)
{
    var previousStatusName = existingProject.StatusShortName;
    existingProject.Status = ProjectModel.Repository.Fetch<ProjectStatus>(proposedUpdatedProject.StatusId);
    changes.Add(new FieldChange { FieldName = "Status", PreviousValue = previousStatusName, NewValue = existingProject.StatusShortName });
}

if (proposedUpdatedProject.TechOwnerId != existingProject.TechOwnerId)
{
    var previousTechOwnerName = existingProject.TechOwnerName;
    existingProject.TechOwner = ProjectModel.Repository.Fetch<Person>(proposedUpdatedProject.TechOwnerId);
    changes.Add(new FieldChange { FieldName = "Tech Owner", PreviousValue = previousTechOwnerName, NewValue = existingProject.TechOwnerName });
}
```

NOTE: that all objects are derived from the same object called BaseObj.  Also note that I am not just putting the values of the comparable fields into FieldChange object (id versus Name property)

Comment: you may want to give [codereview.se] a try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a method [`attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), for example called `ComparableAttribute`.
Then you can decorate all methods in these objects with this attribute.

You can use reflection in the method you are making the comparison and iterate through all `Comparable` properties. The code would be much shorter (one iteration, instead of 20 `if` statements).

If you need custom information for certain properties, you could specify it via the `ComparableAttribute` attribute, as parameters.

The compare method would still take as parameters two instances, but you'll end up with a much smaller implementation. You could even cache the `PropertyInfo`s for your types, so you don't reflect at each comparison.

Comment: can you clarify how you would indicate the relationship between StatusId and StatusShortName with this approach?

Comment: @leora: I'd do it with parameters in the `ComparableAttribute`. For example: `Comparable(Name="Status", ValueProperty="StatusShortName", LookupPropertyType=typeof(ProjectStatus))`. In the compare function you could use this to generalize the code you have now inside the `if` statements.

Comment: @leora: Missed the id. Should be `Comparable(Name="Status", IdProperty="StatusId", ValueProperty="StatusShortName", LookupPropertyType=typeof(ProjectStatus))`. If I come to think about it, this should be a class attribute, not a method attribute, since you only need a subset of an object's properties.

Comment: what do you mean this should be a class attribute?  would you list every single comparable field (the attribute you listed) at the top of the class?

Answer (score 0):

Why not reflect into the structures:

```
existingProject
```

And compare all fields.  By writing the code long-hand this way, you are adding quite a bit of information to the problem like the association between the StatusID and the StatusName, but if you choose some proper naming conventions, you could potentially automate the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use  `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface ? Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) for information on it. You simply have to implement it, and subscribe to the event. One more [link](http://bernhard-richter.blogspot.in/2010/02/tracking-changes-made-to-poco-objects.html)